# Perl Net::FTPSSL doesn't work properly - timeout when trying to transfer data

Tags: perl, cpan

I have to switch the transfer mode of pure-ftpd from regular ftp to ftp with TLS.
So I've switched the config flag TLS to 2 (only TSL, no regular FTP).

The connection and the transfer of files is working fine with filezilla.

Now I have a perl script which is getting some files from the server using NET::FTP.

This is the main functionality:

```
use Net::FTP;

$ftp = Net::FTP->new("[SERVERNAME]", Debug => 1)
  or die "Cannot connect to [SERVERNAME]: $@";

$ftp->login("[USER]",'[PASSWORD]')
  or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->cwd("/")
  or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->dir("/")
  or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->get("somefile.txt")
  or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->quit;
```

To rebuild the GET functionality, I'm trying to use the CPAN Module NET::FTPSSL with the following script snipplet:

```
use Net::FTPSSL;

  my $ftps = Net::FTPSSL->new('[SERVERNAME]', 
                  Port => 21,
                              Encryption => EXP_CRYPT,
                  Croak => 1,
                  Trace => 1,
                              Debug => 2
                  )
    or die "Can't open [SERVERNAME]\n$Net::FTPSSL::ERRSTR";
  $ftps->login('[USER]', '[PASSWORD]') 
    or die "Can't login: ", $ftps->last_message();

  $ftps->cwd("/anyfolder") or die "Can't change directory: " . $ftps->last_message();
  $ftps->quot("PASV");
  $ftps->nlst() or die "Error: " . $ftps->last_message();
  $ftps->list("/anyfolder") or die "Can't change directory: " . $ftps->last_message();
  $ftps->binary() or die "Can't change directory: " . $ftps->last_message();
  $ftps->put("anyfile.txt") or die "Can't get file: " . $ftps->last_message();
  $ftps->get("anyfile.txt") or die "Can't get file: " . $ftps->last_message();

  $ftps->quit();
```

This script is running fine through the authentication process.
When it comes to a filetransfer it stopps until the regular timeaut is reached.

The debug output of the script looks like this:

> SKT <<< 220-Welcome to Pure-FTPd. SKT <<< 220-You are user number 1 of
>   100 allowed. SKT <<< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
>   SKT <<< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server. SKT <<<
>   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity. SKT >>>
>   AUTH TLS SKT <<< 234 AUTH TLS OK.
>
> > > > USER +++++++ <<< 331 User <++++++> OK. Password required
> > > >         PASS ******* <<< 230-User <++++++> has group access to:  100 <<< 230-This server supports FXP transfers <<< 230 OK. Current directory
> > > >         is /
> > > >         CWD /rollout <<< 250 OK. Current directory is /anyfolder
> > > >         PASV <<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***.***.***.***,27,254)
> > > >         PBSZ 0 <<< 200 PBSZ=0
> > > >         PROT P <<< 200 Data protection level set to "private"
> > > >         PASV <<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***.***.***.***,145,153)
> > > >         --- Host (***.***.***.***)  Port (37273)
> > > >         NLST

So it's possible to connect with the server using filezilla but it is not possible to connect to connect to the server and transfer files using the script.

I know it is most likely not a big thing, but I'm currently not able to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem switching from Net::FTP to Net::FTPSSL, and I found that passing the OverridePASV parameter with the same remote address fixed it.

Comment: my $ftps = Net::FTPSSL->new('[Servername]', 
         Port => 21,
            Encryption => EXP_CRYPT,
         Croak => 1,
         Trace => 1,
         OverridePASV => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            Debug => 2
         )

Didn't do the job..

Comment: Does it still die immediately after Entering Passive Mode ?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work either. I have the feeling it has something to do with the ceertificate. I'm using a self signed certificate with an own CA. The debug log doesn't mention the validation of the certificate.

Comment: The debug log suggests that it's trying to use a private data connection, but there's [an open bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=76108) in Net::FTPSSL which suggests that this isn't currently supported. The [pure-ftpd TLS  readme](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.TLS) says that with --tls=2 you should still be able to do clear data connections, but they'll be refused with --tls=3. Are you able to check the pure-ftpd configuration against the documentation to ensure you're not forcing private data connections?

Comment: Filezille is using the "private" data connection without any problem.  
The only difference between the Filezilla.log and the Debug of my script are two lines:  
08:36:42 Status: Initializing TLS...  
08:36:42 Status: Checking Certifikate...

Comment: I've changed the value of the TLS to 3, that didn't solve the problem.
How do I activate the validation of the certificate?
How do I import the CA_CERT?

Comment: At this point, I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions. There doesn't appear to be any requirement for certificate validation in Net::FTPSSL, but you may be able to pass debug options to IO::Socket::SSL to see more. There's a discussion of how to do this [in the RT ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=76108#txn-1056369) for Net::FTPSSL that I linked earlier.

Comment: by the way.. I'm getting the same error when I'm using total commander to connect to that server.

Comment: [This forum thread](http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=253254) suggests that Total Commander doesn't handle private data connections correctly before TC8 beta 19. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So, you already said that you tried OverridePASV and this didn't work.  Usually, this is the obvious fix, since several FTP servers incorrectly return their IP address in the answer to the PASV command.  If they are behind a firewall, etc., their outward-facing IP address is not the one that they return.

Since you are talking to the server from the WAN, not it's internal LAN, setting up the PASV connection to the IP address it gives you just hangs.  When you use OverridePASV, you can force the passive connection to use the WAN IP address (i.e. the address that you used to connect to it).

Given that OverridePASV didn't work, the problem is more likely that your FTP server is behind a firewall that doesn't allow the passive connection to complete (i.e. the port that the FTP server sets up doesn't get port-forwarded from the WAN) or the FTP server doesn't support passive.  Net::FTPSSL only does passive (leastwise the version of the code that I'm looking at, marked 0.31).  If the FTP server that you're talking to doesn't support PASV or you can't get through to the passive port, the connection will often hang until it times out.  It is probable that FileZilla is using PORT instead of PASV, which is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

$ftps->quot("PASV");

quot send the text to the server for fonctions that are not existing in Net::FTPSSL.

PASV change the way the server work, but because of "quot", the client don't care.

If you want PASV to work, you have to create a new command in NET::FTPSSL.

This new command have to :

1. send 'PASV' to the server, and
2. configure the client to word as a server for the DATA connection.

net::ftpssl use a library for the DATA connection that only work in client mode.